# How to send POST request to PHP file from Swift JSONEncoder

Tags: php, swift, forms, post

I'm having a bit of a problem. I have a struct setup that takes values from text inputs:

```
struct CheckoutData: Codable {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var email: String
    var streetAddress: String
    var streetAddress2: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
    var zipCode: String
    var total: Double
}
```

Then I initialize it and encode it:

```
let checkoutData = CheckoutData(
    firstName: firstName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
    lastName: lastName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
    email: email.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
    streetAddress: streetAddress.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
    streetAddress2: streetAddress2.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
    city: city.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
    state: state.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
    zipCode: zipCode.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
    total: total
)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

let encoded = try! encoder.encode(checkoutData)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.MyApp.com/file.php")!)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = encoded
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in }.resume()
```

And here's the PHP to process that handles sending the email:

```
$emailto = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Mobile Order";

$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$streetAddress = $_POST["streetAddress"];
$streetAddress2 = $_POST["streetAddress2"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$zipCode = $_POST["zipCode"];
$total = $_POST["total"];

$entire = "
    Full name: {$firstName} {$lastName}\n
    Email: {$email}\n
    Street address: {$streetAddress}\n
    Apt #, floor, etc: {$streetAddress2}\n
    City, state, zip code: {$city}, {$state} {$zipCode}\n\n

    Total: ${$total}
";

mail($emailto, $subject, $entire);
```

However, when I receive the email, all of the variables are blank. I've printed the encoded version and it seems to be encoded properly, so it very well might be on the PHP end of things. Sorry that a it's a bit of a code dump, but I can't get this figured out. Thanks so much!

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($_POST)`? And always make sure the post variables exist before you try to use then do that like `$firstName = isset($_POST["firstName"]) ? $_POST["firstName"] : '' ;` this way you prefend undefined errors

Comment: Why do you need to send a JSON object?

Comment: `encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted`: No need to put the pretty formatter, it should be ok.

Comment: @Baracuda078 When I changed `$entire` to that the message had no content + Ah, wasn't aware (obviously I have little experience with PHP) so I'll definitely implement that

Comment: @ElTomato I don't necessarily need a JSON object per se, it was just the only method that I knew of for this

Comment: @KyleHorkley Sorry but I don't understand the first part of your response. Just do a `var_dump($_POST); exit();` at the beginning of your script. That way you can make sure your script is recieving all the variables

Comment: @Baracuda078 Ah, my bad. Where would the var_dump print to though? Sorry for the inexperience

Comment: probably you can see that in your network tab, Use Chrome and do inspect element in the top you see network. when yo make the post request with your javascript you will see the request in there and you can read the response, or write the var dump to a txt file

Comment: @Baracuda078 but this is Swift in an app triggered by a button press. Where would it appear in that case?

Comment: Ah ok I have no experience with Swift, If you cant read the request write the var_dump tot a txt file on w3schools they have an example on how to write to files https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: @Baracuda078 I actually was able to do it via the PHP email but it was blank. I'm assuming that means it's not receiving any of the variables

Comment: I'm not sure you can do a var_dump in the mail() function, and is the swift code running on the same server?

Comment: @Baracuda078 So I tested it by writing var_dump to a test .txt file and it was blank. So I think it's not receiving the variables

Comment: Ok, then the problem is within Swift. I never used that so I cant help you with that

Comment: @Baracuda078 Fair enough. Greatly appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an example of sending an e-mail message through a PHP file at a remote server.

```
// View controller //
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func sendTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async() {
            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.MyApp.com/file.php")!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let to = "tom123@apple.com"
            let sub = "Just testing..."
            let msg = "How are you doing?"
            let from = "George H. Aniston <ghaniston@gmail.com>"
            let postString = "a=\(to)&b=\(sub)&c=\(msg)&d=\(from)"
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
                
                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                }
                
                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}

// file.php //
<?php

$to = $_POST['a'];
$sub = $_POST['b'];
$msg = $_POST['c'];
$from = $_POST['d'];

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

$headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// send email
mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: So you are saying that the author should use encoded url parameters (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in header?) What's wrong about JSON? Is it the PHP par that was not expecting JSON?

Comment: @Larme I too wondered this, but using these parameters didn't seem to make a difference in the final outcome

Comment: This worked great instead of using codable and making it a json object.